# How do I format and style text I am sending to another Word document using Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

the following code below recognises all instances of bold text from all open Word documents and copies them to a newly created Word document.

My issue is with the newly created document.

Can anyone help me to format/style the additional text that I send at the end?

I would like to be able to italize, bold, font colour, size etc to the line:
***.InsertAfter Text:="List of Documents:"*** – Which is my title before the results are sent.

Also, how can I determine the format/style of the text within the variable ***FileNames***?

Also, how can I determine the formatting of the text uniquely to the line:
***ThatDoc.Content.InsertAfter Text:="Can this text be uniquely formatted, i.e. it's own colour, italic, font size etc”***

And uniquely determine the format/style the line: ***ThatDoc.Content.InsertAfter Text:="Can this text also be uniquely formatted, i.e. it's own colour, italic, font size etc”***

So far everything I do affects the whole of ThatDoc and I do not want that to happen.

Any help is very much appreciated.

```
Sub A__GrabTheBolds()
On Error GoTo cleanUp
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Dim ThisDoc As Document
     Dim ThatDoc As Document
     Dim r As Range
     
     Set ThatDoc = Documents.Add

     'iterate over all open word documents

For Each ThisDoc In Application.Documents
      
      Dim FileNames As String, fFound As Boolean
      Dim fWritten As Boolean
      

        Set r = ThisDoc.Range
        
        'Don't check document where the code runs
        If Not ThisDoc Is ThisDocument Then
        
    
            Set r = ThisDoc.Range
            
            With r
                With .Find
                    .Text = ""
                    .Format = True
                    .Font.Bold = True
                End With
                
                Do While .Find.Execute(Forward:=True) = True
                    fWritten = True
                    
                   
                   If r.Bold Then
                      ThatDoc.Range.Characters.Last.FormattedText = .FormattedText
                      ThatDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
                      .Collapse 0
                   End If
                 Loop
                 
            End With
            
            'add filename to list only if bold has been found
            If fWritten = True Then
                FileNames = FileNames & vbCrLf & ThisDoc.Name
                fWritten = False
            End If
        End If
    Next

With ThatDoc.Content
    .InsertParagraphAfter
    .InsertAfter Text:="List of Documents:"
    .InsertAfter FileNames
End With

ThatDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
ThatDoc.Content.InsertAfter Text:="Can this text be uniquely formatted, i.e. it's own colour, italic, font size etc"
ThatDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
ThatDoc.Content.InsertAfter Text:="Can this text also be uniquely formatted, i.e. it's own colour, italic, font size etc"
    
cleanUp:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set ThatDoc = Nothing
Set ThisDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Apply the required style to `ThatDoc.Paragraphs.Last` before you add the content.

Comment: Hi Timothy, can you please expand on what you have written.

The line ".InsertAfter Text:="List of Documents:"" should become?

Comment: Your code inserts the text into the final paragraph of the document, so you need to apply the style you want to that paragraph either before or after you add the text. Can't be more precise than that as your question is too vague. I suggest you do some research on how to apply a style, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.style ; or a bad example as it uses direct formatting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/applying-formatting-to-text

Comment: Thank you Timothy and I apologise for being vague. I managed to solve my goal by further research. I am grateful for your initial comment which did gave me some direction.